# trim and pad in one string method

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method that accept one string and it has to get a string with exactly 5 chars.
There is a possibility the user will insert string with more then 5 chars - in that case I want to trim left.
There is a possibility the user will insert string with more less then 5 chars - in that case I want to pad left.

I know I can do it with if/else condition but I wonder maybe string class has something helpfull to deal with such cases in one command.

What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try padding to 5 chars and then trimming to 5 chars. It doesn't matter that the padding may make it too long because the trimming will fix that! :-)

Comment: String paddedTrimmedString = inputString.PadRight(150).Substring(0,150);

Answer (score 4):

It is a simple order of operations issue, pad first then trim to size... like

```
string hi = "hello world"; //or try = "hi";
hi = hi.PadLeft(5, '0'); 
hi = hi.Substring(hi.Length - 5);
Console.WriteLine(hi);
```

Answer (score 2):

This branches, to be sure, but frankly I think it's neat enough:

```
var maxLength = 5;
var paddingChar = 'x';

input = input.Length > maxLength ?
    input.Remove(0, input.Length - maxLength) :
    input.PadLeft(maxLength, paddingChar);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension of PadRight (or PadLeft) such as:

```
public static string PadRight2(this string value, int exactWidth)
{
    return value.PadRight(exactWidth).Substring(0, exactWidth);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to pad with the character 'A', how about:

```
("AAAAA" + st).Substring(st.Length)
// Note: padded string has length (st.Length + 5)  
// ... so substring offset is ((st.Length+5)-5) = st.Length
```

(on the left), or:

```
(st + "AAAAA").Substring(0,5)
```

(on the right)?

Answer (score -8):

try this:

```
string str = "abcdefghjxd";
 string split = str.Substring(0, 5);
```